# Save credentials in webview-client

Tags: android, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, android-webview

I have a webview in my application:

```
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInstance(this.getApplicationContext()), "HTML");
```

With this webview, I load a authentication (oauth2) page on google or facebook over our own-written api.
There's no problem loading the pages or authenticate with, but we want to save the credentials.

What we want is, that if you want to "authenticate" again, that you don't have to put in your credentials, but the webview should have it saved and login automatically.

Here is a pic, where to "store" credentials: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kkhm.png .
At this page, I want that the webview logIn automatically with the credentials that were save when the user logged in some time before or sth similar.

I know there are some functions to work with, but I don't know how to deal with it :/
please, don't write an alternative to my/our problem, We need a solution for exact the provlem I wrote about.

Edit:

The credentials/login should only in this webview be saved.
And how can I delete them, if I want to delete it as user

Edit2:

I think

```
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
    CookieManager.getInstance();
```

should do this, right?

Edit3:
Can I use these features (in special the JavaScriptInterface) with API 14+15? I mean, I've read, that you can't use this for this API-level, but I don't know where :/